# Adding columns to a FITS table with PyFITS

Tags: python, fits, pyfits

Let's assume I have a fits file with one extension, and the data consists of a table of two columns with 100 elements each

```
data = pyfits.open('path2myfile')[1].data
head = pyfits.open('path2myfile')[1].header
print data['field1'] # print an array with 100 elements
print data['field2'] # print another array with 100 elements
```

Now I want to add to my table a new column, let's say data['field3'], which is another array of 100 elements.

How exactly do I do that ?

Comment: After reading your question a couple times I realized that what you actually have is a FITS table that you want to add a column to.  Please see: http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/latest/users_guide/users_table.html#merging-tables

Comment: Ah thank you, I did not have the right vocabulary. That did it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Iguananaut indicated, the answer can be found here : http://pyfits.readthedocs.org/en/latest/users_guide/users_table.html#merging-tables
But just to mark this question as answered:

```
cols = [] 
cols.append(
    pyfits.Column(name='field3', format='D', array= arrayContainingTheData)
    )
orig_cols = data.columns
new_cols = pyfits.ColDefs(cols)
hdu = pyfits.BinTableHDU.from_columns(orig_cols + new_cols)
hdu.writeto('newtable.fits')
```

Answer (score 0):

@Cehem's answer is right on. But I just wanted to add that Astropy has a much better general purpose [Table](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/index.html) interface that you might find easier to use (for inserting columns among other use cases).

Astropy incorporates PyFITS in the [astropy.io.fits](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/io/fits/index.html) module.  But since you also have access to the better Table interface you can read *most* FITS tables into the Astropy table class like so:

```
>>> from astropy.table import Table
>>> table = Table.read('path/to/fits_file.fits')
```

And that's it.  You can also write the table back out to a FITS file.  Granted, this currently does not support *all* types of FITS tables, but it will work for most--and in the future all.